# Iterating through IEnumerable to display values

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to iterate through an `IEnumerable` to display the values in index 1 in textboxes if `Count != 0`

This is the code for the table on the right:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfoTable(int value) =>
   Partial(
      "_DisplayDMVPartial", 
      _context
      .ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations
      .Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value)
      .ToList()
   );
```

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DmvDob)
    </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DriverLicense)
    </td>
  </tr>
@foreach (Models.ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <!-- 
      <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
        item.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")
      </td>
    -->
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
      @item.DmvDob
    </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">
      @item.DriverLicense
    </td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

This is the code for the textbox link on the left

```
public JsonResult OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo(int value) {
   ExemptionApplicationDmvinformation data =
      _context
      .ExemptionApplicationDmvinformations
      .Where(x => x.ExemptionApplicationOwnerId == value)
      .FirstOrDefault();

   return new JsonResult(new {
      DateOfBirth = data.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy"),
      DriversLicenseNumber = data.DriverLicense
   });
}
```

Model code

```
[Display(Name = "DOB")] public DateTime? DmvDob { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Driver's License #")] public string? DriverLicense { get; set; }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have code which can be shorten to [`DateTime? Test = null; Test.Value.CallSomeDateTimeMethod();`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XgYcih) which obviously would not work ... Exception is pointing you the line ... so the question is ... Are you wana become a programmer or not?

Comment: not sure how the question is unclear, I'm providing all the details and debugging I have come across

Comment: Not sure why you think that you can use `Nullable.Value` if you didn't check if it has value

Comment: ```Nullable.Value``` is nowhere in my code lol. I'm reading records from a database using EF core

Comment: I've already give all clues how to fix it... It's all about accessing  `Nullable.Value`  when this Nullable doesn't has... All you need to is check if it has value and do not access value if it doesn't have one... More over putting your exception into Internet search would return similar questions already asked here

Comment: The exception points you to `OnGetDisplayOwnerInfo()`, so only the few lines here are relevant. Let's have a look at this line: `DateOfBirth = data.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy"),`. There is only one `Nullable` value type: `data.DmvDob` which you try to read using `data.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")`. The exception now tells you that `data.DmvDob` has no value and so it is invalid to read `.Value` here.

Comment: "Nullable.Value is nowhere in my code lol". This is short for: You are using a nullable value type (shortened as "Nullable") and you read the property ".Value" on it. This is what you do here `data.DmvDob.Value`. Do not look for the letters but try to understand their meaning ;-)

Comment: but how do I access the 2nd record in the list, I need IEnumerable somewhere and the foreach statement to loop through the records

Comment: Replace `data.DmvDob.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")` with `data.DmvDob?.ToString("MMddyyyy") ?? "value you want to see if BmvDob has no value"`.

Comment: I'm not trying to see the value of null, I want to skip them and move to the next record until I find actual values for both columns as shown in my images

Comment: The code you have posted does not do anything with lists. You posted code for an exception and you have the reason for this exception. If you want something different you will need to post a new question that contains the relevant code.

Comment: I had to edit my question

Comment: you say "if Count != 0". Count of what? You say "in index 1". Are you saying that you want to show the second element of the list in the textbox? Or that you have something like an `IEnumerable` of lists, and you want to do something for the second item of each list?

Comment: You call `FirstOrDefault()`. Do you mean to call `First()` instead? `FirstOrDefault` means you might not find an item, but then you immediately proceed as if you were guaranteed to find one. `First()` would mean that you think you are guaranteed to find an item. (It would still throw if there wasn't one, but that is what `First()` is for.) (In fact you may want `Single()` since you probably want exactly one item; but First() might be more error tolerant if you think you might have duplicate data or something.)

Comment: basically my model is an ```IEnumerable``` as shown in the images, it has 3 indexes. When you loop through the first index the values of both columns are null, loop to the next index and both columns have values, when loop finds values on both columns, exit the loop and I want those values to be populated in the textboxes. I've tried ToArray but not working

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution myself

```
public JsonResult OnGetDisplay(int value)
{
  IEnumerable<ModelName> model = _context.ContextModelName.Where(x => x.Id == value).ToArray();

  foreach (var item in model)
   {
        if (item.Column1 == null || item.Column2 == null)
        {
            // Ignore null values
        }
        else
        {
            DateProperty =  item.Column1.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy");
            StringProperty = item.Column2;
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult(new { DateProperty, StringProperty });
}
```

Comment: consider accepting your own answer to indicate the solution